otel to loki distributed - ERROR ": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)"
I have a loki distributed instance deployed via helm chart and another chart deploying otel. I need otel to send the logs to loki to later visualize in grafana.
I've tried multiple configuration on my otel values.yaml but no matter what do I always get the error:
Exporting failed. Will retry the request after interval. 
{
  "service": "loki", 
  "kind": "exporter", 
  "data_type": "logs", 
  "name": "loki", 
  "error": "Post 
  "http://loki_address:3100/loki/api/v1/push": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)", 
  "interval": "6.604788454s"
 }

this is my otel values.yaml:
mode: deployment
replicaCount: 1
image:
  repository: "otel/opentelemetry-collector-contrib"

presets:
  clusterMetrics:
    enabled: true
  kubernetesEvents:
    enabled: true
config:
  receivers:
    otlp:
      protocols:
        grpc: {}
        http: {}

  extensions:
    headers_setter:
      headers:
        - action: insert
          key: X-Scope-OrgID
          value: kaas
    health_check: {}

  exporters:
    azuremonitor:
      connection_string: "InstrumentationKey=AZURE_KEY;IngestionEndpoint=https://AZURE_REGION.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/"
    loki:
      endpoint: "http://loki_name.k8s_namespace.svc.cluster.local:3100/loki/api/v1/push"
      auth:
        authenticator: headers_setter
      tls:
        insecure: true
        insecure_skip_verify: true

  processors:
    batch:
      send_batch_max_size: 10000
      timeout: 1s
    memory_limiter:
      check_interval: 1s
      limit_mib: 4000
      spike_limit_mib: 800

  service:
    extensions: [headers_setter, health_check]
    telemetry:
      logs:
        level: debug
        initial_fields:
          service: loki
    pipelines:
      traces:
        receivers: [otlp]
        exporters: [azuremonitor]
      logs:
        receivers: [otlp]
        processors: [memory_limiter, batch]
        exporters: [azuremonitor, loki]

The azuremonitor exporter is working fine.
My loki instance does not require authentication and is configured in Grafana without HTTP headers, what am I missing?
